# Does AWS Lambda charge for time an async .NET Core function is awaiting?

Tags: c#, .net, aws-lambda

AWS Lambda .NET Core functions have the ability to be defined as async entry point methods.

If I'm using "await" in my functions to wait for IO to respond, am I charged the full amount still?

What is the benefit of writing everything as async await in this scenario vs not using async/await?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you will be charged for 'awaiting' functions. Lambda will charge you for execution time of your program (e.g. until the function `return` is called).

From the billing perspective, there is no benefit to using `async`-`await` keywords here.

What these would do is potentially (depending on what it is that you are `await`ing) fractionally reduce the load on underlying AWS infrastructure while these calls are running.

Comment: That's a major bummer. Would be cool if they could detect I'm just waiting and give me some extra runtime or something.

Comment: Unfortunately - You're using resources even if those resources are locked in a wait state since nobody else can use them until you release them.